# Why is this select ordering not working as expected?

Tags: mysql, select

My select statement is

```
SELECT styleNo , right( concat( '######', trim( styleNo ) ) , 6 ) AS keyn 
FROM `styles` WHERE 1 ORDER BY keyn
```

StyleNo is varchar(6) and contains mostly numeric strings from 3 to 6 characters long, some of which include a leading or trailing capital letter. The aim is to show the styles in magnitude order.

I want 100 to 999 first, then A00 to Z99, then 1000 to 9999 and A000 to Z999 etc.

I get these results.

```
 101    ###101
 180    ###180
 105    ###105
 104    ###104
 102    ###102
 123    ###123
 124    ###124
 432    ###432
1004    ##1004
1001    ##1001
1002    ##1002
1003    ##1003
1006    ##1006
1234    ##1234
1231    ##1231
1255    ##1255
1288    ##1288
2005    ##2005
2006    ##2006
2007    ##2007
2008    ##2008
```

Why are the results not in ascending order?  keyn is what I expect.

I am using MySQL 5.1.36-community with UTF-8 characters sets everywhere. None of the styleNo shown contain anything other than '0' to '9' characters.

Some further information: I changed the sql statement to

```
SELECT styleNo , right( concat(repeat('#',5), trim( styleNo ) ) , 6 ) AS keyn
FROM `styles` ORDER BY keyn ASC
```

and tried with different values for the 5.  3 and larger should all produce suitable values for keyn.

However 3, 4 5, 6 and 7 all produce different orders of the results - all wrong. 
A value of 8 works for the first 75 lines in my test file.

Without understanding why, I don't feel confident this is correct.

Comment: why not `ORDER BY LENGTH(keyn) ASC, keyn ASC`? If I see this correctly you want the shorter strings to come first in all circumstances, right?

Comment: What happens if you use `FROM styles ORDER BY 2`

Comment: @mvds - I don't want it by the length, but by the magnitude. Besides, all keyn are 6 chars long because of how they are computed.

Comment: @Jim Garrison - Nothing. 2 and 1 both convert to True.

Comment: @Ian, please reread my comment.  Not `where 2` but `order by 2`

Comment: If I use 8 hashes, instead of 6, I get the right order. Very odd!

Comment: @Jim - Whoops. I have tested it, and the results are exactly the same.

Comment: @Ian I don't see the problem. The sample output you show matches your expected output exactly.

Comment: @Ike - Becuase of the order by keyn, I expecte 101, 102, 104, 105, 123, 124, 180. That is not the order that appeared.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't look closely enough at your output. Your query ***should*** work as you expect. What storage engine are you using, and what version of MySQL?

Comment: @Ike - ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci on MySQL 5.1.36-community under 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: @ian sorry I meant to say `ORDER BY LENGTH(TRIM(styleNo)),TRIM(styleNo)`. `TRIM(styleNo)` doesn't have a fixed length, right?

Comment: i think the simplest solution is to sort by the original numeric value in `styleNo` like so: `ORDER BY styleNo`

Comment: @ian I'm suggesting it partly because using this 6-hashes method you may be burying a bug that will bite you one day.

Comment: @mvds - Your solution works, and I agree the other appears to trigger a bug. Pls enter it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to order by the length of the (trimmed) field, so you could also say:

```
SELECT styleNo FROM `styles`
               WHERE 1
               ORDER BY LENGTH(TRIM(`styleNo`)),TRIM(`styleNo`)
```

potentially saving you a headache as well when `styleNo` is changed one day to be longer than 6 chars.